# Typescript: Return "this" from generic base class

Tags: generics, typescript, derived-class

I want to return "this" from the base class as the generics type parameter.

```js
class ExampleClass<T> {
    public returnThis = (): T => {
        return <T>this;
    }
}
```

I know that i cannot cast to T because typescript doesn't know that T derives from ExampleClass.
But is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just return type `this`:

```
class ExampleClass<T> {
    public returnThis = (): this => {
        return this;
    }
}
```

It's covered in the [Polymorphic this types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) section of the docs.

---

#### Edit

No, it will return the type of the actual instance, for example:

```
class BaseClass {
    public returnThis(): this {
        return this;
    }
}

class ExampleClass extends BaseClass {}

let base = new BaseClass();
let base2 = base.returnThis(); // base2 instanceof BaseClass

let example = new ExampleClass();
let example2 = example.returnThis(); // example2 instanceof ExampleClass
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20BaseClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20returnThis()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ExampleClass%20extends%20BaseClass%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20base%20%3D%20new%20BaseClass()%3B%0D%0Alet%20base2%20%3D%20base.returnThis()%3B%20%2F%2F%20base2%20instanceof%20BaseClass%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20example%20%3D%20new%20ExampleClass()%3B%0D%0Alet%20example2%20%3D%20example.returnThis()%3B%20%2F%2F%20example2%20instanceof%20ExampleClass%20))

Comment: but then the return type is ExampleClass. Is there a way that the return type is T?

Comment: Oh, well, I revised my answer with an example anyhow :)

Comment: Also, I suggest not to use instance methods like that (using the arrow function) but to define them on the prototype instead. Otherwise you won't be able to override that method and call `super`

Comment: so it is not possible to override an arrow function in the base class? didn't know that, thanks again ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's because arrow functions are added to the instance in the constructor and are not added to the prototype. You can find some questions about it in SO, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218959/typescript-how-to-call-method-defined-with-arrow-function-in-base-class-using-s

Comment: Hey guys, this question and answer looks strange, I assume you removed some comments. OP ask to return `this` as T at the same time as `this` extends `ExampleClass<T>`? The answer contains an edit as a negative response to something, but I don't see the question that edit/example responds to,

Comment: @Alex No, no comments were removed. I revised my answer after the first comment. The OP then posted the 2nd comment a few seconds before I updated my question, hence the 3rd comment.